# How to manage anchors (links with hashtags) for internal pages while using the LinkTransformator?

Tags: hyperlink, anchor, aem

I'm working on a project using AEM 6.4. When configuring links to internal pages, the standard link-transformater from aem change the href-attribute from internal page-links to "real" links including .html.

This does not work if we put an anchor at the end of the link.

This is what happen to a link without an anchor:

```html
<li class="_linkbox__listitem _linkbox__listitem--link">
    <a class="_linkbox__link" href="/en/components/searchresults.html" target="_self">
        <span class="_linkbox__title">link without anchor</span>
        <svg class="_linkbox__icon">
            <use xlink:href="#_svg-icon-arrow-right"></use>
        </svg>
    </a>
</li>
```

This is the same link but appending an anchor:

```html
<li class="_linkbox__listitem _linkbox__listitem--link">
    <a class="_linkbox__link" href="/content/test/gf/unitedkingdom/en/components/searchresults#ananchor" target="_self">
        <span class="_linkbox__title">link with anchor</span>
        <svg class="_linkbox__icon">
            <use xlink:href="#_svg-icon-arrow-right"></use>
        </svg>
   </a>
</li>
```

The link is not transformed and so it is not useful on the published page.

I can not believe that it is only possible to make references on the same page or to disable the transformator as #-anchors are possible since I guess ever?

Does anyone have the same conditions for their project or can provide a solution to this problem?

Comment: Is this problem still unsolved? If yes, how is the link getting into the html? Using HTL and adding the data via properties.XXX?

Comment: Are you writing your own custom transformer for this? If so, what does your logic look like?

Comment: @OliverGebert yes it is and yes, that's the way we do it.

Comment: @AhmedMusallam we have not written anything to solve that problem. We have an own transformer, but for other issues.

Answer (score 0):

I fear you need to create a SlingModel or any other backend logic that

- checks for #xxx in your URL
- maps the part before # with a resource resolver
- adds an extension if needed
- adds the anchor at the end.

This can than be used in your frontend code.

HTH

Comment: For now I fear too.